# Save web user clicking information on database

Tags: javascript, user-tracking

I'm working on a tracking system which will save a web user's activity to a **database**, it will be a simple system which I want to only intiate a save "when" a user click's on a specific link.

I have found so many applications which have a lot of features such as chart, history and etc. My problem with them is I don't want anything that complex and I want to develop it myself.

Could you please help me figure out which JavaScript functions should be used for this task.

(how can I gather information from browser and send it to database when specific links are clicked)

Comment: are you purely doing this in javascript? you will need some type of scripting/programming language to do the database inserts. Very vague question, no one here is going to just do your work for you! Show what you have tried and someone will be happy to help you out.

Comment: just use Google Analytics, why re-invent the wheel? I would only roll my own solution IF all users were 'registered' and it was a highly specific app.  But based on your requirement google analytics fits.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the time a link was clicked in [milliseconds since epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) via:

`<a onclick="alert('Link 1 clicked at '+new Date().getTime())" href="http://www.example.com">Link 1</a>`

If you want to convert this to regular date and time [here's](http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm) a useful converter (with Javascript source code included). Now instead of an `alert` function you can write your own function which takes that time and uses it in the way you want. However, as Robert already correctly pointed out, you would need a programming language at the server end to catch this value and store it in a database.

Answer (score 0):

**No need of Javascript**

```
I want to save "when" a user click on "which" link.
```

When: You can use server time. update DB for each request on server.

Which: Update requested file name (say 'x.php') in DB for each request.

If you are not requesting any page from server and doing locally some action on page.
Use AJAX call and send **location.href**.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know Ajax :(

Comment: Improve your question and requirements, then only anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

no need for javascript. simply make a redirect page like example.com/red='the link the user clicked'.
the code in html looks like

```
  <a href="http://example.com/red=google.com&from=sourcePageId">google.com</a>
```

and output like

> [google.com](http://example.com/red=google.com)

during the redirecting phase simply save to your db the value of the site from which the user clicked, the value what the user clicked, and than redirect the user to the specified clicked site.

Comment: this is, however, good only for the links, which lead outside your server.